# JBoss 7.1.1: log4j configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure logging for JBoss 7.1.1. I have a well defined log4j.xml which works fine with JBoss 4. This xml file configures logging for various categories of my application. My goal is to use the file instead of [configuring in standalone.xml](https://community.jboss.org/message/622614).

Here is what I tried to make it work in JBoss 7.1.1

- Changed standalone.conf.bat by adding `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:<path to log4j.properties>`. This did not work. It was because standalone.bat was redefining it in the end as follows:

`:RESTART
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% ^
 "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=%JBOSS_LOG_DIR%\boot.log" ^
 "-Dlogging.configuration=file:%JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR%/logging.properties" ^
    -jar "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar" ^
    -mp "%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%" ^
    -jaxpmodule "javax.xml.jaxp-provider" ^
     org.jboss.as.standalone ^
    -Djboss.home.dir="%JBOSS_HOME%" ^
     %*`

- I have then changed the value from logging.properties to log4.xml in the above script which did not seem to work.
- I then added [exclusions to jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration?) which did not work

Questions:

- Is there a way to configure logging without changing default standalone.xml at all ?
- Is there way to put my configuration into logging.properties of `configuration` folder ?

Anymore insights are welcome.

Comment: shouldn't that read -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///your/path/log4j.xml? IE three slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure logging in your application with a log4.xml, but you cannot configure logging at the server level with a log4j configuration.

For the most part you will be able to translate the log4j configuration into the standalone.xml configuration. The one current caveat would be using log4j appenders. While there are some equivalent handlers not all appenders are covered.

That said if you're feeling froggy and you want to build from source, in the [JBoss AS upstream](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as) or even the [7.1.3.Final tag](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/zipball/7.1.3.Final) you can define log4j appenders as custom handlers.

Comment: Thank you. I have modified standalone.xml and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
i am also facing same problem. My application has log4j.properties files, and not able to create the log files configured in properties. please let me know how you have been resolved the issue.

    My application deployed on Jboss AS 7.1.1. 

My application log4j.properties file: 
    ############################
    # Log configuration file .
    ############################

    log4j.rootLogger=debug

    log4j.logger.com.fourthdti=debug, filePerfLog

    log4j.appender.filePerfLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.filePerfLog.File=filePerfLog.log
    log4j.appender.filePerfLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.filePerfLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p - %X{requestId} - {%c{1}} - %m%n
    log4j.appender.filePerfLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.filePerfLog.MaxBackupIndex=5
    log4j.appender.filePerfLog.DatePattern=DAY.TOP.1
```

Comment: Sirji, In eclips log4j is working with Jboss 7.1.1 final but hibernate log is not working.... You can see my configuration on following link...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834772/log4j-is-working-but-hibernate-logs-is-create-in-to-the-hibernate-log-file